# Wi-Fi shows that it's connected, but the store and apps say that there is no connection

Tags: 8.1, internet

I've tried restarting the phone, taking out battery and sim, and connecting and disconnecting from the Wi-Fi network. But nothing has worked so far. Strangely enough my Castle Clash works but nothing else that requires a connection.

My phone is a Microsoft Lumia 640 single sim with Windows Phone 8.1

Comment: Can other devices on the same WiFi see the Internet?

Comment: Sounds like the DNS settings for your wifi network are incorrectly configured.  Does your phone work on another wifi network?

Answer (score 2):

Try restarting your phone a few times and wait at least 10 seconds before You turn him on again. Delete the internet connection from your phone and wait at least a minute. Then fill in the password of the internet connection and normally it'll work. If it doesn't There will be something wrong with your phone or your access point.